# Managed SQLite Upgrade

Tags: android

Android Developers have to use SQL lite for Android application, that is easy, but the problem comes when we have to upgrade the database version, we have to remove old database and create new database on upgrade, so if we want to add just one column, we have to remove all user data, is there any component or source code that manage the database upgrade, so if it only need one column, just add one column, not delete all tables.

Comment: for a better explanation, you should also ask for the reason, `why do we have to delete whole database on alteration of a single table?`

Comment: Perhaps because he followed [Android Developer official guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is completely wrong

> when we have to upgrade the database version, we have to remove old database and create new database on upgrade

In your onUpgrade method, it would look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
String upgradeQuery = "ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD COLUMN yourcolumn TEXT";
if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2)
     db.execSQL(upgradeQuery);
}
```